# How to set PTR Record on Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I was trying to add PTR Record to Azure App Service cause I have problem with our emails being blacklisted cause no PTR Record for IP.

I git info from MS that this is not possible directly. Is there any other way to use PTR record with App service? I found solution to create small VM with PublicIP, Reverse Proxy and add PTR Record there but for me this is really bad solution as this VM failing would cause site to be down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is **no** solution for setting PTR record on Azure App service.

Comment: Thanks, got that response from Azure support also. Tried to add Application Gateway before my App service to use its PublicIP with PTR Record but it is not working too as App Gateway IP couldnt be use with reverse fqdn...